# Recyclerview swipe direction right

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was wondering if you could use the `itemtouchhelper` to dismiss items , ONLY when user swipes to right? I'm using this code, but the direction does not work

```
public class CrimeTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
        private CrimeAdapter mMovieAdapter;

        public CrimeTouchHelper(CrimeAdapter movieAdapter){
            super(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN,     ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
            this.mMovieAdapter = movieAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            //TODO: Not implemented here
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            //Remove item
            Log.e("DIRECTION", direction + "");
            if(direction == 8) {
                mMovieAdapter.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simple to do. You can use this code,

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new
            ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                @Override
                public boolean onMove(
                        final RecyclerView recyclerView,
                        final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                        final RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onSwiped(
                        final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                        final int swipeDir) {
                    adapter.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            };

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(
            simpleItemTouchCallback
    );
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(itemsRecyclerView);
```

You can pass `ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT` as the second parameter of the constructor which actaully takes the direction.

Use the `onSwipe()` method to perform the operation you want to do, like removing the item from the adapter.

Hope this helps. Do let me know if you face any problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Set it in the super method in the constructor of CrimeTouchHelper.

The second parameter is swipe directions, so just pass ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT

```
super(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
```

After that, you can remove the 'if' check in #onSwiped

Your current if check in #onSwiped will not prevent the swipe. Assuming 8 is the int value for swiping right, all you're doing now is preventing the adapter from removing the item (but that item will still visually be swiped away).

Answer (score 0):

You should override getMovementFlags method and set swipe flag to ItemTouchHelper.START in your customItemTouchHelper.Callback class

```
 @Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    // Set movement flags based on the layout manager
    if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
        final int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
        final int swipeFlags = 0;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    } else {
        final int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
        final int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }
}
```

This will block the swipe from left to right.To do the opposite direction set flag to ItemTouchHelper.END